# Does $\texttt{DTIME}(O(1))$ contain only finite languages?

Tags: complexity-theory

My question is pretty much just the title.

It is pretty easy to see that any finite language can be solved in $O(1)$ time. For this reason, every finite languages is in $P$, $L$, and $DTIME(O(1))$.

But are finite languages the *only* languages that can be decided in constant time?

Comment: Assuming that in your TM model the head points to the left symbol of the input, $O(1)$ time basically means that you can (fully) analyze the first $c$ bits of the input for some constant $c$. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, for example the language of all possible input strings can be decided in O(1) time. Just return True without reading the input. More generally, note that you can only read a constant prefix of the input in constant time.